# Curvature of a totally symmetric Christoffel symbol of the first kind

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature, coordinate-systems

If a Christoffel symbol of the first kind:
$$\Gamma_{cab} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial g_{ca}}{\partial x^b} + \frac{\partial g_{cb}}{\partial x^a} - \frac{\partial g_{ab}}{\partial x^c}\right)$$
is totally symmetric in all three indices in some coordinate system, does it have any implication for the flatness of the curvature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Christoffel symbol is **not a tensor**. It has nonlinear transformation properties under coordinate changes, see [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols) for more details.

As a consequence of this, the equation

$$ \Gamma_{\mu \nu \sigma} = \Gamma_{\mu \sigma \nu} $$

is **not a tensor equation** meaning that it can be satisfied in one coordinate system, but not in another. It thus makes no sense to even talk about $\Gamma$ being symmetric in lower indexes, except for the first two (in which case it is possible to show that the notion of symmetricity is coordinate-independent).

Edit: it is worth mentioning that the impact of symmetricity in these two indexes is well-known: it is the *absence of torsion*.

Edit 2: in your notation (which is quite different from the one which is commonly used) Cristoffels are symmetric in the last two indexes, not the first two. Any other symmetricity condition is coordinate-dependent and, consequently, ill-defined.

It only makes sense to say that $\Gamma$ is symmetric in *some coordinate patches*, because it may simplify computations.

Comment: Good point. It seems that in the case where the question arose the only allowed coordinate transformations where affine, making it possible to talk about the symmetry. The situation seems too restrictive to have generally interesting consequences.